# How do Java enum values work without calling the name method (+thymeleaf)

Tags: java, thymeleaf

In all examples of how to use enums in Java, i see that you use the `.name()` method, (or `.toString()`.

However, it seems that using it **without** the parentheses also works (?!).

HOW / WHY? :D

```html
<div th:text="${user.accountStatus.name == 'APPROVED'}"></div> <!-- prints true correctly -->
```

(For extra context: It's quite confusing when reviewing code in a team where frontend developers (who don't know java) use it like this. Without knowing exactly why this works, from a language-agnostic standpoint, it *looks* like a bug)

Comment: It's not supposed to be regular Java syntax. See [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standarddialect5minutes.html), particularly the `book.author.name` example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thymeleaf syntax is not Java. Thymeleaf offers its own way of accessing properties, in this case using `.name` to access the Java method `name()`. But that's fully configurable, you could configure it so that `foo.bar` would also return `APPROVED`.

Just don't assume that you can now also just use `.name` instead of `.name()` in plain Java code.